# Edit MAMP Start Screen

Tags: mamp, homescreen

I have been trying to figure out if there is a way to edit your start screen so that when you click on "Open start page" it will show your custom page. How could I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: why would you like to change it anyways? hmm, just asking. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit your `httpd.conf` found on `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/` and look for this:

```
Alias /MAMP "/Applications/MAMP/bin/mamp"
```

Then change that to your custom page:

example:

```
Alias /MAMP "/Users/me/custompage"
```